# Restore SQL is very slowly

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

We are executing a SQL restore query but have some problems with the time.
We have three physical server hosting SQL server. There is a storage device that is connected to them. 
 When we start the restore query, the query get finished in 5 minutes on a server. But on the other two server it takes about an hour to finish the query.
According our monitor, the data part is doing well in the restore process but when it comes to the logs it a kind of stuck in this level and takes about 40 minutes to finish the job. One out of three servers is doing fine and finishes the query in 10 minutes but the others last an hour.
The storage is newly bought and well configured. the OS of the servers are newly installed and configured. Different HBA cards have been tested. we are sure that there is no problem from physical equipment.
We are really stuck in here whether it is a windows problem or server or SQL.

Comment: Make sure the SQL Server service account is granted the Windows `perform volume maintenance tasks` privilege so that it can use [instant file initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-instant-file-initialization).

Comment: Thanks Dan. It was enabled. Without it it would take three times longer. It's a weird problem.

Comment: I have to ad that restore on local disks are ok and fast enough but on SAN it takes lots of time.